# Taking into account that "If statement with initializer" got in the c++17 standard, why is a initializer list not supported?

Tags: c++, c++17

"If statement with initializer" is the topic of the proposal [P00305r0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0305r0.html). The proposal got in the c++17 standard and it allows to use a new version of the if statement for c++. An example is:

```
if (auto p = m.try_emplace(key, value); !p.second)
{
    FATAL("Element already registered");
} 
else 
{
    process(p.second);
}
```

Pushing the idea a little further one can think of an initialization **list**. Just like that:

```
if (auto a = func1(), auto b = func2(); !a.BoolVal && !b.BoolVal)
{
    SomeProcess();
} 
else 
{
    SomeOtherProcess(a,b);
}
```

Could an if statement with initialization list make it in the standard?

Comment: What kind of answer do you want? *"Could an if statement with initialization list make it in the standard?"* Is completely opinion-based.

Comment: Yes. You are right. Should I delete the post?

Comment: I don't think you can do that after you get an upvoted answer.

Answer (score 1):

This declaration

```
auto a = func1(), auto b = func2();
```

is syntactically incorrect.

You may write

```
auto a = func1(), b = func2();
```

and correspondingly

```
if (auto a = func1(), b = func2(); !a.BoolVal && !b.BoolVal)
```

For example

```
if ( auto x = 10, y = 20; x < y ) std::cout << "x is less than y\n";
```

Otherwise you need to have several declarations in the if statement that makes the if statement too complicated.

That is this new feature of the if statement is based on the current syntax of declaration.

Comment: I don't see your point. Of cause the if-statement with initialization list is syntactically incorrect. This is because it is not part of the c++ standard.

Comment: @BlueTune It means that you have to say not about the if statement but about  redesigning declarations in whole.

Comment: It's worth noting that this use of `auto` with multiple declarators requires all the declarators to have the exact same type.

Answer (score 1):

> Could an if statement with initialization list make it in the standard?

It is highly unlikely. The grammatical rules that [govern the `init-statement` part of an `if` statement initializer](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/stmt.select#1) are the same rules that [govern the `init-statement` part of a `for` loop](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/stmt.for#1). So it adopts the same limitations.

As for whether the committee would consider a proposal to generally allow statements that accomplish this goal, probably not. If they were to consider it, it would likely take the form of allowing multiple variables in a single `auto` declaration to deduce different types (at present, attempting to do that is a compile error):

```
auto a = func1(), b = func2(); //Not a compile error if `func2()` returns the same type as `func1()`.
```

That being said, the committee explicitly made this ill-formed back in C++11 for a reason. That reason probably hasn't changed since then.

You can use a `tuple` coupled with structured binding as a decidedly inelegant way to achieve the same effect:

```
auto [a, b] = std::tuple(func1(), func2());
```

But the longer this declaration gets, the greater the distance between each "variable" and its initializer, and the less readable this becomes. Of course, having multiple variables in one statement becomes less readable the longer it gets, which is probably why the committee imposed the limitation in the first place.

Comment: "the committee explicitly made this ill-formed back in C++11". I don't think that's true - that compiles fine (assuming `func1()` and `func2()` return the same type). Usual rules with declarators apply [example](https://godbolt.org/z/ZWWTBZ).

Comment: @Barry: That's what I said: "Not a compile error if `func2()` returns the same type as `func1()`." That's the thing the committee made ill-formed.

Comment: Oh, ok. It was a bit unclear what the "this" referred to - you meant it to refer to "allowing multiple variables ... to deduce different types" but the example with `auto` is closer.

Answer (score 0):

According to the proposal link you provided, the code:

```
if (init; cond) E;
```

is equivalent to

```
{ init; while(cond) { E; break; } }
```

Init section is just a usual variable definition, and your `auto a = func1(), auto b = func2();` would be incorrect.

Also it is made so to be consistent with `for`, which doesn't support it either.